# Unable to see the default value show up in shared preferences

Tags: java, android

so I am currently working on an app, for which I created a settings activity. In it, I used shared preferences to save the settings for the user. The code is working fine, and the settings are being saved, however, I am unable to see the default value of the reminder (which should be true, but it shows to be false)... I want it to be true on the first run. Pl help.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String SETTINGS_PREFERENCES = "com.example.taskmasterv3.SettingsPreferences";
    SwitchCompat switchReminder, switchNotifications;
    Button btnSaveSettings;
    boolean remind;
    boolean notify;
    ImageView ivReminders, ivNotifications;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        switchReminder = findViewById(R.id.switchReminder);
        switchNotifications = findViewById(R.id.switchNotifications);
        btnSaveSettings = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveSettings);
        ivReminders = findViewById(R.id.ivReminder);
        ivNotifications = findViewById(R.id.ivNotifications);

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean reminder = preferences.getBoolean("remind", true);  // this is what I'm talking about
        boolean notification = preferences.getBoolean("notify", false);

        if (reminder)
        {
            switchReminder.setChecked(true);
            ivReminders.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm_on);

        }
        else
        {
            ivReminders.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm_off);
        }
        if (notification)
        {
            switchNotifications.setChecked(true);
            ivNotifications.setImageResource(R.drawable.notifications_on);


        }
        else
        {
            ivNotifications.setImageResource(R.drawable.notifications_off);


        }
        

        btnSaveSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();

                if (switchReminder.isChecked())
                {
                    remind = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    remind = false;
                }
                if (switchNotifications.isChecked())
                {
                    notify = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    notify = false;
                }
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("remind", remind);
                editor.putBoolean("notify", notify);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you check if the preference file exists and if that value was present? How did you ensure that it shoudl return the default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Activity: (Where you would save the boolean true in sharedPref)**

```
SharedPreference sharedpref = getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
                                    editor.putString("token", token.getBoolean(true));
                                    editor.apply();
```

**2nd Activity:(Where you would get the boolean true in sharedPref)**

```
SharedPreference sharedpref = getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);

Boolean token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I have just started out coding. I didn't quite understand what you mean. Could you please try and explain

Comment: just check that you have gone through the right way to get sharedpref or not. i just uploaded a sample example to make you understand how to save and get a sharedpref value correctly.

Comment: Thanks! I added the getApplicationContext line in getting the boolean place, and it works like a charm now! Thank you!!